# Background Image not showing in program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

so I'm trying to get this image to load as a background when this class is displayed, however, my program just runs and no image is displayed. I'm new to python and coding in general so I'm probably doing something wrong that's easily fixable but yeah, thanks in advance! (Just some context, I'm making a Memory Game and if more code is needed just request away!)

```
import tkinter as tk  # imports tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont  # imports font as tkfont
import random  
import string  
import sys 
import time  
import pygame 


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):  # class - Basically my Main hub

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)  
    self.geometry("1024x576+155+60")  
    self.title("Memory Mania")  

    self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='verdana', size=45, weight="bold", slant="italic")

    container = tk.Frame(self)  
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)  
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  

    self.frames = {}  
    for F in (Login, MainMenu, Tutorial, Tutorial2, Difficulty, Settings, 
    EasyDifficulty, MediumDifficulty, HardDifficulty, InsaneDifficulty,= 
    EnterCharacterScreen, CorrectScreen, IncorrectScreen, Level2,
              WinGameScreen):

        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("Login") 

def show_frame(self, page_name): 
    frame = self.frames[page_name]  
    frame.tkraise()  


class Login(tk.Frame): 

def __init__(self, parent, controller):  
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="#2699C3") 
    self.controller = controller  

    background_image = tk.PhotoImage("giphy.gif")
    background_label = tk.Label(parent, image=background_image)
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    background_label.image = background_image
```

Comment: You place the Label in `parent` with `place`, but `parent` is the Frame your complete `Login` Frame was placed in using `grid`. You want to place the image in the frame using `tk.Label(self, ...)`

Comment: Also, use `tk.PhotoImage(file="giphy.gif")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to use a `gif` in the background, but `tkinter` doesn't work well with `gif`s so you have to drive the animation yourself. An animated gif consists of a number of frames in a single file. `Tk` loads the first frame but you can specify different frames by passing an index parameter when creating the image. For example:

```
frame2 = PhotoImage(file="giphy.gif", format="gif -index 2")
```

If you load up all the frames into separate `PhotoImage`s and then use timer events to switch the frame being shown (`label.configure(image=nextframe)`). The delay on the timer lets you control the animation speed. There is nothing provided to give you the number of frames in the image other than it failing to create a frame once you exceed the frame count.

See the [photo](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/photo.htm#M49) Tk manual page for the official advice.

Comment: I sort of understand what you're trying to say, but since I'm new to python I'm not too sure how to put this into practice

Comment: You're assuming it's an animated gif, but [Tkinter PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) only accepts GIF and PGM/PPM images, so using a static gif in Tkinter is not uncommon.